# Old function is not working anymore even though there are no changes (Works on Chrome, but not on the Windows Application)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows-store-apps, windows-store

So I'm working on an application which includes a function that changes the page that is shown, depending on the value of a variable:

```
function()
  {
    if(something && somethingElse)
    {
      return <Page1 />;
    } else if(something) {
      return <Page2 />;
    } else {
      return <Page3 />;
    }
  }

render()
  {
    return (
      <>
        {this.function()}
      </>
    );
  }
```

Now **everything works on the web version**, but the Windows application (which is the same code but just has a homepage with links to the pages) doesn't load one of the pages.

The way the variables are changed is through a submit like below.

```
onSubmitTerms(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    setSomethingElse(true);
  }

render()
  {
    return(
      <PageLayout onClickStartBtn={this.onSubmitTerms}>
        //some code
      </PageLayout>
    );
  }
```

Again, everything works on the web version: all pages are loaded correctly. When the form is submitted the correct page loads. But on the Windows version, the form won't submit: the button is clickable but when I click it nothing changes (the new page is not shown).

I'm running out of ideas of where the problem could be. I'm using JS and React.js. Please help.

Comment: Please include all relevant code. Where are you calling onClickStartBtn?

Comment: @CodeSpirit The <PageLayout> component contains a footer with a button in it:  `<footer className="footer">
                <button className="btn btn-ghost btn-lg btn--pill" onClick={props.onClickStartBtn}>Start Exam</button>
            </footer>`